# Is there a way to have a rolling window, that varies, based on an arbitrary Series of integers of the same time series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The need arose because I want to calculate something like:

```
df['result'] = np.where(df['data1'] == True, df["data2"].rolling(window).max(), 0)
```

However: `window` is practically `df['window']`; a Series of data in the same time series; it contains integers and they may look something like `[2,2,2,3,3,2,2,4,2,2]`.

What's the most vectorized or other efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please present a fuller example with data we can play with and what your desired output should be given that example.

Comment: @piRSquared yeah I may do that later since I know it helps for developing answers. In the meantime: I think this question is almost exactly the same topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064501, however: they don't have a vectorized version of an answer there (though I do not know if it exists).

Comment: Don't you worry, I've got a vectorized solution for you.

Comment: It appears it's extremely slow for large dataframes with any method I tried, possibly because SIMD hardware may prefer a constant nature of windows, but I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: Since the problem shifted purely to performance, I made a new question for that specifcially, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71805439

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,14])
a = np.random.randn(20).cumsum()
w = np.minimum(
    np.random.randint(1, 4, size=a.shape),
    np.arange(len(a))+1
)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': a, 'Window': w})
df

        Data  Window
0  -0.602923       1
1  -1.005579       2
2  -0.703250       3
3  -1.227599       1
4  -0.683756       1
5  -0.670621       2
6  -0.997120       1
7   0.387956       3
8   0.255502       1
9  -0.152361       2
10  1.150534       3
11  0.546298       3
12  0.302936       3
13  0.091674       1
14 -1.964947       1
15 -1.447079       2
16 -1.487828       1
17 -2.539703       1
18 -1.932612       3
19 -4.163049       2
```

---

### Vectorized variable window rolling maximum

```
idx_base = np.arange(len(df))
windows = df.Window.to_numpy()
data = df.Data.to_numpy()

idx_max = np.concatenate([
    np.arange(position-(window_size-1), position+1)
    for window_size, position in zip(windows, idx_base)
])

idx_pos = np.repeat(idx_base, windows)
data_windowed = data[idx_max]

out = np.full(data.shape, data.min())
np.maximum.at(out, idx_pos, data_windowed)
```

The answer is now in the `out` variable.  Let's look

```
df.Data.iloc[idx_max].groupby(idx_pos).max().to_frame('Pandas').assign(Numpy=out)

      Pandas     Numpy
0  -0.602923 -0.602923
1  -0.602923 -0.602923
2  -0.602923 -0.602923
3  -1.227599 -1.227599
4  -0.683756 -0.683756
5  -0.670621 -0.670621
6  -0.997120 -0.997120
7   0.387956  0.387956
8   0.255502  0.255502
9   0.255502  0.255502
10  1.150534  1.150534
11  1.150534  1.150534
12  1.150534  1.150534
13  0.091674  0.091674
14 -1.964947 -1.964947
15 -1.447079 -1.447079
16 -1.487828 -1.487828
17 -2.539703 -2.539703
18 -1.487828 -1.487828
19 -1.932612 -1.932612
```

---

### Appendix

Look at `idx_max`.  You'll see how we end up vectorizing this.

```
print(idx_max)

[           #  Position   Window
  0         #         0        1
  0  1      #         1        2
  0  1  2   #         2        3
  3         #         3        1
  4         #         4        1
  4  5      #         5        2
  6         #         6        1
  5  6  7   #         7        3
  8         #         8        1
  8  9      #         9        2
  8  9 10   #        10        3
  9 10 11   #        11        3
 10 11 12   #        12        3
 13         #        13        1
 14         #        14        1
 14 15      #        15        2
 16         #        16        1
 17         #        17        1
 16 17 18   #        18        3
 18 19      #        19        2
]
```

Comment: Thanks since this appears to produce the same results with an apply() method. However: it's still extremely slow to the point of being unusable compared to the performance of a rolling().max given a constant integer window. But I suspect it's impossible to be fast because SIMD hardware may prefer that constant nature of windows.

Comment: Since the question shifted purely to performance, I accepted this answer and made a new question specifically for performance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71805439

Comment: Have you explored the use of Numba at all?

Comment: No, but I believe the first answer there does directly use numba and compares it to cython, though it brought an issue with correctness of results.

Comment: I noticed something odd with this method: while it's still noticeably slower than the method https://stackoverflow.com/a/71806274/277716 found at the new question, I get the vague impression it's now faster than it was when I first tested and the only thing different I can think of is installing mumba/llvmlite but it remains the same after they are uninstalled so it might be unrelated. It's not crucially important though since that other method remains more performant (they do appear to produce the same results though).